# Internal error in the .NET Runtime (80131506) / CLR.DLL

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I get CLR.dll error consistently when running my app on Windows Server environment via RDP.

The cause seems to be me spawning phantomJS within a TPL Parallel For Loop. This is the code I use to spawn process.

```
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "phantomjs.exe";
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
                { 
                   Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
                };
                process.Start();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();

                // Don't leave orphan phantomJs
                if (process.WaitForExit(3 * 60 * 1000) == false)
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
                else
                {
                    process.Close();
                }
            }
```

Parallel code sits above and is simple. But it calls many methods that eventually hits that process start code above.

```
Parallel.ForEach(urls, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 },
                (url) => KickOfPhantomJs(url)
                );
```

FYI This code is being run via Quartz.NET not sure if that matter but worth mentioning.

I have tried:

1. Disabling GC via config file
2. Setting app to x86
3. Tried spawning phantomjs using another console app (which didn't help the way I tried it)
4. Updating from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 and installing all newest updates

Although the WinForms app crashes with the CLR.DLL, the actual function runs to completion. Because tasks are run via quartz.net the actual application can finish running through all tasks even though the UI has frozen and the error message box is being displayed.

Comment: Where's the Parrallel for loop and how does it interact with this code?

Comment: Simple parallel loop, (see above edit). However, the stack is quite deep, 5-6 method calls down before it reaches the process.start. There is no recursion, just nested function calls.